# How not display particular post?

Tags: posts

Ex: In my field "POSTS" I have 10 posts. Let's say I do not want to display the post "8", which has the ID (looking in the URL) "155".

How can I do to not display this post on my home page? I want to display it only when I click on the category.

Looking at the documentation and Googling I saw that you can not display the entire category. Just use the `cat` and argument be negative the category ID `($args = array ( 'cat' => ID_CATEGORY));`.

But it does hide the whole category. I want to hide only 1 post (home) in this category.

I also found [this code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_Single_Posts_by_I.D_From_Home_Page):

```
function exclude_single_posts_home($query) {
//Caso esteja na home  
   if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    //Não exiba estes posts
$query->set('post__not_in', array(187,174,166));   } }

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_single_posts_home');
```

As I understand it, he takes the post ID and does not display it is in case home. Well, I did not catch: /

Anyway,

How do I prevent certain post of home by ID? So he only appears when I click on the category.

obs: My home is being displayed in `page.php`

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me. Can you try it and replace the excluded ID by the id of post you want to exclude.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_specific_post_id' );
function exclude_specific_post_id( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 'YOUR_EXCLUDED_POST_ID_HERE' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: This code exclude the post in my Dashboard "Posts". In my site the post is still displayed. Thank you anyway!